# Need to create plist programatically with access today widget extension target

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I need to access plist from `TodayViewController` from created in main target. So I need create plist with access of Today widget target access also.

I've created plist like this, But I need access this plist from today extension target

```
let InfoDict:NSDictionary = [
    "ParentInfo":"Mathew"
]

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let isWritten = InfoDict.write(toFile: self.getPlistPath(), atomically: true)
    print("is the file created: \(isWritten)")

}


func getPlistPath()->String{

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = documentDirectory.appending("/UserConfig.plist")

    if(!fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)){
        self.saveGlobalValuesToPlist()
    }

    return path

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your plist file in a App Group folder:

Step 1: To create App Group: Project Navigator -> YOUR_APP_TARGET -> Capabilities -> Activate App Groups -> add App Groups ID (usually group.YOUR_APP_BUNDLE)

Step 2: Add this App Group ID in your widget target also by activating App Group in the Capability and choose this SAME App Group ID

Step 3: Save your plist in the App Group folder. Use this code to retrieve url of this folder from both `TodayViewController` and your main app:
`guard let appGroupURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: YOUR_APP_GROUP_ID) else {
        return
    }`

Hope this helps.